# 日本語に違和感: 「完全なサイト」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

モバイル版から通常版に戻るためのリンクの訳が「完全なサイト」になっていますが違和感があります。「PC版」とかの方が良いと思います。
また「モバイル」も「モバイル版」とすると、より分かりと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

翻訳を改善しました。次回のビルドに適用します。